# How to register a Expression Language in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I already created a provider **with a security function**. Following [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/extending.html#using-expression-providers), i created my own ExpressionLanguage class and registered the provider.

```
namespace AppBundle\ExpressionLanguage;

use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage as BaseExpressionLanguage;
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ParserCache\ParserCacheInterface;

class ExpressionLanguage extends BaseExpressionLanguage
{
    public function __construct(ParserCacheInterface $parser = null, array $providers = array())
    {
        // prepend the default provider to let users override it easily
        array_unshift($providers, new AppExpressionLanguageProvider());

        parent::__construct($parser, $providers);
    }
}
```

I'm using the same function `lowercase` that is [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/extending.html#using-expression-providers). But now, i have no ideia how to register the ExpressionLanguage class to be loaded in my Symfony project.

I get this error every time i try to load a page with the custom function in the annotation:

> The function "lowercase" does not exist around position 26.

*I'm using Symfony 2.7.5.*

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: No, i found some bad ways, like replace the default class, but nothing really native.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to use your custom function the security expressions? In that case, register the expression language provider you created as a service and tag it with [`security.expression_language_provider`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags#security-expression-language-provider):

```
services:
    app.security_expression_language_provider:
        class: AppBundle\ExpressionLanguage\AppExpressionLanguageProvider
        tags:
            - { name: security.expression_language_provider }
```

Comment: Thank you Wouter. I did it before try using my own ExpressionLanguage class. Same error, `The function "lowercase" does not exist around position 1.`

Comment: Where do you call your expression? In a controller? In a service?

Comment: Thanks. I'm calling in the annotation security inside a controller.

Comment: I created a repository doing the same thing: https://github.com/iagomelanias/symfony-expression-language-testing. I got the same error.

Comment: @IagoMelanias you did not tag your service. Compare your services.yml code with the example code I posted in my answer.

Comment: Hello Wouter, thank you. I made a mistake in this specific example, but i already have tested using the tags option correctly. I [updated the example](https://github.com/iagomelanias/symfony-expression-language-testing/commit/fbc799b5528830b1ba2d331ba0b419f218892b0a) and got the same error. `The function "lowercase" does not exist around position 1.` Thank you for the support anyway.

Comment: Did you check that `AppExpressionLanguageProvider::getFunctions()` is called? Providers are registered in `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AddExpressionLanguageProvidersPass`, so if everything is configured properly it should add `addExpressionLanguageProvider` method call for `security.access.expression_voter`and register your provider.

Answer (score 2):

The tag `security.expression_language_provider` is only used to add language providers to the expression language used in symfonys security component, or more specifically in the ExpressionVoter.

The @Security-Annotation of the FrameworkBundle uses a different instance of the expression language, which has no knowledge of the language providers you created.

To be able to use custom language providers in the @Security-Annotation, I solved this using the following compiler pass:

```php
<?php

namespace ApiBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

/**
 * This compiler pass adds language providers tagged
 * with security.expression_language_provider to the
 * expression language used in the framework extra bundle.
 *
 * This allows to use custom expression language functions
 * in the @Security-Annotation.
 *
 * Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInection\Compiler\AddExpressionLanguageProvidersPass
 * does the same, but only for the security.expression_language
 * which is used in the ExpressionVoter.
 */
class AddExpressionLanguageProvidersPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if ($container->has('sensio_framework_extra.security.expression_language')) {
            $definition = $container->findDefinition('sensio_framework_extra.security.expression_language');
            foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('security.expression_language_provider') as $id => $attributes) {
                $definition->addMethodCall('registerProvider', array(new Reference($id)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the expression languages used by the ExpressionVoter and FrameworkBundle are both configured using the same language providers.